# No-redirecting redirect in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

The title of question is a mess and nonsense, but I don’t know how I should name it better.
I try to navigate my user to target page with saving his subdomain and domain name in the browser address bar.
User has `page.usersite.com`, that connects to my server (by IP from CNAME `app.service.com` IN `page.usersite.com`), then the server detects HOST and it has to open target page without redirect (`app.service.com/<target_page_id>`). `.htaccess` code below does what I need, but it redirects. I don’t need the redirect, I need to save `page.usersite.com` in the browser address bar:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://app.service.com/%{HTTP_HOST} [NC,L,QSA]
```

Is there an opportunity to do it?

Comment: Is "app.service.com" served from the same http server?

Comment: @arkascha my server serves service.com, app.service.com. .htaccess from this question is at var/www/html directory of apache.

Comment: Then why do you rewrite to an absolute URL? That always results in an external redirection, since it is a URL. Rewrite to a _path_ instead, then you get an internal rewrite. So something like `RewriteRule ^ /%{HTTP_HOST} [L,QSA]` ...

Comment: And also check if you can't implement that rule in the http server's central configuration for the virtual host (probably the default virtual host) instead of using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess").

Comment: @arkascha Just now I've tried `RewriteRule ^$ /app.service.com/%{HTTP_HOST} [L,QSA]`, but I got 404 error (The requested URL was not found on this server.)

Comment: There is a difference between `^$` and `^`. And also between `/app.service.com/%{HTTP_HOST}` and `/%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Comment: @arkascha I edited `000-default.conf` and `apache2.conf`. Now request goes to `app.service.com`. This is good. But I have new problem - `app.service.com` is written in ReactJS, and this app ignores GET-parameters at `RewriteRule ^$ ./index.php?page=%{HTTP_HOST} [L]`. If I try to check `print_r($_GET)`, then I see this value, but React app ignore it.

Comment: Well, there is little I can do with that. If the application chooses to ignore that data, then it does so. You need to change the app then, I'd say.

Comment: @arkascha thank you! I will proceed to look for a solution.